# Java Insertion Sort with an Array List of objects?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a class Card which contains value (int), suit (String) and faceValue (String). It seems like a regular insertion sort on Card.value should work fine. I just use the whole object when moving things around. For some reason, this crashes and burns. It ends up duplicating the highest card into every element except for a random element that I can't understand.

value, suit, and faceValue are pulic, also.

This is my code:

```
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Card> Array) {

    int i,j;
    Card key = new Card(0, "","");

    for (i = 1; i < Array.size(); i++) {
        key.value = Array.get(i).value;
        key.suit = Array.get(i).suit;
        key.faceValue = Array.get(i).faceValue;
        j = i;
        while((j > 0) && (Array.get(j - 1).value > key.value)) {
            Array.set(j,Array.get(j - 1));
            j--;
        }
        Array.set(j,key);
    }


}
```

I checked this against Wikipedia's pseudo code, and I can't find any fundamental difference. I've been through the debugger a dozen times, and I can't see any reason for the compiler to do what it's doing. Does anyone have an idea why it's not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Is using the language features an option? Having Card implement Comparable and using ```Collections.sort```

Comment: @oschlueter I think that he uses this algorithm for practice.

Comment: `Array.set(j,key);` is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: also, `Array.set(j,Array.get(j - 1));` does not swap

Comment: you probably want to `remove` and `insert`.

Comment: Algorithm is fine, problem is that he is setting same object (`key`) to multiple places.

Comment: @DRAX : using `set` is not really fine, in this case

Comment: He cannot use `insert`. You probably mean to `add`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: yes, add, that performs an insert but is poorly named

Comment: the algorithm itself is fine: start: array(1, 3, 5, 2, 0) i=4, j=4 key.value = 0 array.set(j,array.get(j - 1)); => array(1, 3, 5, 2, 2) j=3 array.set(j,array.get(j - 1)); => array(1, 3, 5, 5, 2) j=2 array.set(j,array.get(j - 1)); => array(1, 3, 3, 5, 2) j=1 array.set(j,array.get(j - 1)); => array(1, 1, 3, 5, 2) j=0 array.set(j,key); => array(0, 1, 3, 5, 2)

Comment: @Kicsi: so many issues with that. if ever there is a new field in Card, since the object themselves are not sorted, but copies of themselves, it breaks. During the while loop the list is in a very uncertain state, with duplicate values. I don't understand why you don't simply have `Card key = Array.get(i)`.

Comment: @njzk2 i know that, but "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime" - writing down the perfect sollution is not always useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At every cycle, you insert the object "key" into the list (Array.set(j,key);). So, at the end your whole list will be made of references to the object "key". So when you set key.value, key.suit and key.faceValue at the end, you are setting the fields of every element of your list, because your list consists of references of the same object.

move Card key = new Card(0, "",""); inside the for cycle. Like this:

```
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Card> Array) {

    int i,

    j;

    for (i = 1; i < Array.size(); i++) {
        Card key = new Card(0, "","");
        key.value = Array.get(i).value;
        key.suit = Array.get(i).suit;
        key.faceValue = Array.get(i).faceValue;
        j = i;
        while((j > 0) && (Array.get(j - 1).value > key.value)) {
            Array.set(j,Array.get(j - 1));
            j--;
        }
        Array.set(j,key);
    }


}
```

gl with your studies :)

Comment: again, `set` is not `insert`.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, I never thought of that, but it actually makes sense. I really appreciate that! Thanks for the well wishes. =)

Comment: Keep in mind, that this code makes unnecessary object duplicates.

Comment: also this does not scale. How does it work if you have tens of properties in your object? not to mention that you destroy the initial objects and replace then by new ones. good way to break things elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to extend ginz's answer.

Java objects are passed by reference.
So you are changing one object and setting it to multiple indexes.

To visualize (**before** and **after**):

[image: visual representation]

For **after**: Please note that not all indexes must reference to same object. Some of them could remain unchanged.

---

Better approach would be to move objects, instead of trying to duplicate them.

Also, by Java standard, name of properties (variables) should always start with small letter.

Here is working code:

```
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Card> array) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
        Card tmp = array.get(i);
        j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (array.get(j - 1).value > tmp.value)) {
            array.set(j, array.get(j - 1));
            j--;
        }
        array.set(j, tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, normally I'm pretty good with the lowercase names, I'm not sure why I differed this time. Thanks for pointing that out. =)

Answer (score 3):

You're setting all the fields of `Array`(OMG, please rename it!) with the same element: `key`.  So, all the elements would be the same.

Comment: Piling on the "rename it, for the sake of all that is holy!" bandwagon along with you...

Answer (score 2):

The basic algorithm is

- for each element
- search for the first smaller element going downward
- insert element right after that

So, in your case:

```
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Card> cards) {

    for (int i = 1; i < cards.size(); i++) {
        int value = cards.get(i).value;
        j = i;
        for (j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (cards.get(j).value <= key.value) {
                break;
            }
        }
        cards.add(j,cards.remove(i));
    }
}
```

One important point here is that at no point does the array contains duplicated values (which happens when you use `set`)

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterator for getting the elements.

```
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> arrL) {
    Iterator<Integer> it = arrL.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        int new_element = it.next();

        int j = arrL.indexOf(new_element);
        while(j>0 && arrL.get(j-1)>new_element){
            arrL.set(j, arrL.get(j-1));
            j--;
        }

        arrL.set(j, new_element);
    }
 }
```